# Размещение сайта Asp.Net на IIS сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp

При размещение сайта Asp.Net на сервере IIS вылетает ошибка, прикрепленная на скриншоте[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Есть предположение, что надо установить SSL сертификат. 
Подскажите прав ли я? 
Можно ли сделать какую то заглушку без сертификата?
И как получить бесплатно сертификат SSL или это только платно?

Comment: все верно, бесплатный сертификат можно взять здесь https://letsencrypt.org/ru/. чтобы отключить принудительный редирект на https уберите строчку в startup.cs `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` ну конечно если вы используете net core

Comment: Нет,у меня framework. Тут только качать сертификат или может тоже что то в web.config или где то еще закомментировать?

Comment: тогда проверяйте bindings в IIS, должен быть настроен протокол http на 80 порт, хотя порт может быть любым

Comment: И еще. Для сертификата нужен домен, на который сертификат ссылается. Если вы используете localhost, то для localhost сертификатов не существует, использовать либо самоподписный сертификат, либо отказаться от использования SSL для localhost.

Comment: А как отказаться от использования SSL?

Comment: Вроде разобрался с этим. К базе данных идет подключение. Но теперь при стандартной регистрации asp.net framework вылетает такая ошибка: "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".   А адрессная строка выглядит так:"https://localhost/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FA" причем тут не все сиволы.. тут скопировал, чтобы в размер сообщение влезть, так символов около 3000. Как это исправить

Comment: http error 400 the size of the request headers is too long - вот ошибка